# Rails 4 uninitialized constant for module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a new rails 4 app I anm getting an unintialized constant error for a module. The module is named ProcessBill and is located in lib/process_bill.rb

console error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant BillsController::ProcessBill):
```

controller code:

```
class BillsController < ApplicationController

  include ProcessBill
```

lib/process_bill.rb

```
module ProcessBill
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Have you added lib to your autoload path? This was necessary in Rails 3, I'm not sure if it's still required for Rails 4.

Try adding this into the class definition in `config/application.rb` -

```
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Answer (score 44):

I had this problem too with the lib directory with Rails 5 and it appeared in production but not in development. To fix it you need to add the lib directory to eager_load_paths. Here is the relevant part from my application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

Comment: This article explains why: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2016/07/22/solutions-to-potential-upgrade-problems-in-rails-5/

Answer (score 8):

This will also work in Rails 5 in your application.rb file:

```
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib/notifier')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding this line to the top of your controller:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/process_bill.rb"
```

Comment: You can also do just "require 'process_bill', as the `lib` directory is already on the load path.

Comment: take care, this kills auto reloading!

Comment: i was needed to do - "require 'process_bill.rb'"