# Ruby on Rails 4.0 - Loading and using a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Reading around, I get confused about the right way to load and include a module in Rails 4.
I'd like to include this module in several models of my application:

```
module SimpleSearch
  def self.search(filter)
    if filter.present?
      where('name like ?', "%#{filter}%")
    else
      where('TRUE')
    end
  end
end
```

The file path is `lib/simple_search.rb`
Thanks to Michael's suggestion, I updated the `config/application.rb` to help loading the module (question 3 is solved):

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

In the model, I include:

```
class BusinessRule < ActiveRecord::Base
extend SimpleSearch
```

and get a new error at execution:

```
undefined method `search' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_BusinessRule:0x00000003670770>
```

1. Is `extend` relevant here ?
2. Do I use the correct syntax, module and file name ?
3. Is there something to configure to make sure the lib/module is loaded or is it convention ?

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,

Fred

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this into the class definition in `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Taken from here:
[Rails 4 uninitialized constant for module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007685/rails-4-uninitialized-constant-for-module)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, the `search` function is a class function, so it is relevant to include it using `extend`.

Then, the module definition should not refer to `self`.

Here is the code update that works fine:

```
module SimpleSearch
  def search(filter)
    if filter.present?
      where('name like ?', "%#{filter}%")
    else
      where('TRUE')
    end
  end
end
```

Your observations are welcome,

Best regards,

Fred