# Ruby on Rails: Using Modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails, but I have almost completed the online course on Lynda. I am stuck on 14-5 "Using the positionMove module". The tutorial is in Rails 3 while my version is Rails 4. I have the solution code, however it does not work for me. I have put my file position_mover.rb in the lib directory. Then in my subject model I require and include the module like this:

```
require 'lib/position_mover'
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base

  include PositionMover
  ...
end
```

I used the methods in this model in the Subject controller just like the instructor. However, when I go to run my app on the Subjects index page I get the error:

```
cannot load such file -- lib/position_mover

app/models/page.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/views/subjects/list.html.erb:23:in `block in_app_views_subjects_list_html_erb__420960863_60005508'
app/views/subjects/list.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_subjects_list_html_erb__420960863_60005508'
app/controllers/subjects_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

I have tried many different approaches that I found online such as adding it to the class definition ([Ruby on Rails 4.0 - Loading and using a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405287/ruby-on-rails-4-0-loading-and-using-a-module)) or moving it to a different directory and specifying the path. How do I achieve the same result in Rails 4? What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/position_mover"
```

or

```
require_relative 'lib/position_mover'
```

You also can auto-loading lib files.

in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I have tried all of those options and I still get the same error every time.

Comment: Can you tell me the path of lib directory?

Comment: it is root/lib/position_mover.rb

Comment: It turns out I left a require statement in my page.rb and section.rb files. I added lib to the autoload path in the config/application.rb like you suggested and needed to remove all my require statements from my other models and now the app works.